# Deserialize empty JSON array into empty TreeMap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm new to Java, and I'm wondering how to deserialize an empty JSON array into an empty Java object of type `TreeMap<String, MyOtherClass>`.

Currently, I'm attempting to deserialize a JSON file with an array of objects, and each object into a class called `MyClass`. The class is roughly as follows:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyClass {

  private final String propertyOne;
  private final String propertyTwo;
  private final String propertyThree;

  @JsonSerialize(contentAs = MyOtherClass.class)
  @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = MyOtherClass.class)
  TreeMap<String, MyOtherClass> otherThings = new TreeMap<>();

  @JsonCreator
  public MyClass(
      @JsonProperty("propertyOne") String propertyOne,
      @JsonProperty("propertyTwo") String propertyTwo,
      @JsonProperty("propertyThree") String propertyThree) {
    this.propertyOne = propertyOne;
    this.propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
    this.propertyThree = propertyThree;

  // Getters and setters below
  @JsonSetter("otherThings")
  public void setOtherThings() {
    if (this.otherThings == null || this.otherThings.isEmpty()) {
      this.otherThings = new TreeMap<>();
    }
  }
  }
}
```

One of the entries in the original JSON is this field `otherThings`. I've represented this entry using `MyOtherClass`, which handles the properties that `otherThings` could contain.

Currently, this works perfect for *serialization*, and for deserialization when `otherThings` is populated. However, when I have something like the following:

```json
{
  "propertyOne": "This is propertyOne!",
  "propertyTwo": "This is propertyTwo!",
  "propertyThree": "This is propertyThree!",
  "otherThings": []
}
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,org.something.model.MyOtherClass>` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (URL); line: 7, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.something.model.Order["lines"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1741)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1515)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(StdDeserializer.java:222)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:447)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:351)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:184)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:355)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3572)
    at org.something.model.MyClass.populateMyClassFromJson(MyClass.java:148)
    at org.something.service.MyClassService.displayMyClassObject(MyClassService.java:96)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

I've tried:

- Using `ObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT)`, but that doesn't really help since `otherThings` gets instantiated as `null`.
- Using the `JsonSetter` for `setOtherThings` you see above. This has to be careful because I don't want to overwrite `otherThings` if it already contains things inside of it.

**EDIT:** Here's also the method `populateMyClassFromJson` if it helps:

```java
public void populateMyClassFromJson() throws IOException {
  List<MyClass> myClassList = mapper.readValue(new File("/path/to/my_classes.json"), new TypeReference<>() {});
  Map<String, MyClass> myClassMap = myClassList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getId, Function.identity()));
  myClassTreeMap.putAll(myClassMap);
}
```

Comment: You could add this map as parameter to your constructor and check there if map is null. This would work with `ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT`. And there would be no need for `JsonSetter`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm trying to see if there's a way to do this in Jackson natively. I could do that, but I don't like explicitly passing `null` into the constructor if I don't have to.

Comment: Is there now some mixup with MyClass & MyOtherClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize (I believe it was clear from the start): as error states the problem is that Jackson tries to deserialize field as TreeMap which is not going to work since the in JSON there is an array `[]`.

However your setter seems a bit odd to me. I believe you should have something like this (updated based on your comment and update):

```
@JsonSetter("otherThings")
public void setOtherThings(MyOtherClass[] arr) {
    this.otherThings = List.of(Optional.ofNullable(arr)
            .orElse(new MyOtherClass[0])).stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyOtherClass::getId, Function.identity(),
                (o1, o2) -> o1, TreeMap::new));
}
```

Of course you should also handle the case when the array is not empty.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the method `populateMyClassFromJson` above. I'm using it to populate the `TreeMap` which holds all `MyClass` instances, along with the `ID` which uniquely identifies them.

I'm using a `Map` to hold `MyClass` instances, and them I put them in a `TreeMap`. So the structure is:

`TreeMap<String, MyClass> myClassTreeMap` which itself holds `MyClass` instances, which contain `otherThings`, which is `TreeMap<String, MyOtherClass>`. This is as deep as the nesting goes, no more.

I can use `Object[]` instead? Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @ScottCrooks Add also the JSON you are trying to deserialize to be exact. Assuming you are deserializing MyClass with non empty list/arrray of  MyOtherClass.

Comment: @ScottCrooks Somewhat gues based update :)